# Changing color of certain line in VB RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, string, richtextbox

I would like to ask you how to change the color of a certain string in RichTextBox using VB. For example, I would like to change the color of lines starting with "Make" to red color.
Would you please give me some examples ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Select the text and use the SelectionFont and/or SelectionColor property:

richtextbox.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
richtextbox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;